# OSRM API: find distance to nearest emergency station

Tags: python, typescript, google-maps-api-3, openstreetmap

I have a typescript project and I am trying to get the distance to the nearest police station (and later I also add fire station). I'm using typescript for this

I tried this url I found in the internet:`https://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/${lon},${lat};nearest?annotations=distance&exclude=motorway,toll`
but it seems not to work at all.

I looked further in the documentation and I am not sure which I should use: [route/v1/driving](https://project-osrm.org/docs/v5.24.0/api/#) or [nearest/v1/driving](https://project-osrm.org/docs/v5.24.0/api/#services). I did not find a solution that has both (?) .

So the general goal would be to get coordinates of my location and get the distance (in km) to nearest police station and nearest fire-station.

For example I also tried the following function:

```
import axios from "axios";
async function getNearestPoliceStation(
  lat: number,
  lon: number
): Promise<[number, number]> {
  try {
    console.log("input lat and lon", lat, lon);
    const url2 = `https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&q=police+station&limit=1&lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}`;
    const response2 = await axios.get(url2);
    console.log(response2.data[0]);
    const nearestPoliceStation = response2.data[0];
    if (!nearestPoliceStation) {
      return [-1, -1];
    }

    const lati = parseFloat(nearestPoliceStation.lat);
    const longi = parseFloat(nearestPoliceStation.lon);

    return [lati, longi];
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return [-1, -1];
  }
}
```

but when I input [49.85349, 8.65859](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=14/49.85349/8.65859) (in Germany), it finds me the nearest police station in New Jersey: [40.7007047, -75.1719147](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=14/40.7007/-75.1719)

A python code for this would also be helpful. I tried some tests on Python, using Google Maps API (instead of TS and OSMR) and that also was not too straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

Here [a jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/afarber/sz92v78u/55/) which would display police and fire stations as markers on the map and when you click one of them a driving route will be drawn as a blue line:

[image: OpenStreetMap with fire and police stations and routes]

My Javascript code sends the following [Overpass API](https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1uuf) query to fetch nodes with specific tags:

```
[out:json][bbox:{{bbox}}];
(
  node[amenity=fire_station];
  node[amenity=police];
);
out center;
```

Then the nodes are drawn as markers and when you click one of them a driving route is requested from the OSRM server:

```js
'use strict';

function processOsrmReply(data) {

  if (data.code === 'Ok') {
    data.routes.forEach(function(route) {
      groups.routes.addData(route.geometry);
    });
  }
}

function sendOsrmRequest(lat, lng) {
  groups.routes.clearLayers();

  var url = 'https://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/car/' +
    parseFloat(startMarker.getLatLng().lng).toFixed(6) + ',' +
    parseFloat(startMarker.getLatLng().lat).toFixed(6) + ';' +
    parseFloat(lng).toFixed(6) + ',' +
    parseFloat(lat).toFixed(6) +
    '?overview=simplified' +
    '&alternatives=3' +
    '&steps=false' +
    '&annotations=false' +
    '&geometries=geojson';

  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.onload = function() {
    if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
      var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
      processOsrmReply(data);
    }
  };
  request.send();
}

function processOverpassReply(data) {

  data.elements.forEach(function(element) {
    if (element.type === 'node') {
      var amenity = element.tags.amenity;
      var name = element.tags.name;
      var lat = element.lat;
      var lng = element.lon;

      L.marker([lat, lng])
        .bindPopup(amenity + '<br>' + name)
        .on('click', function(ev) { sendOsrmRequest(lat, lng); })
        .addTo(groups[amenity]);
    }
  });
}

function sendOverpassRequest() {
  groups.fire_station.clearLayers();
  groups.police.clearLayers();

  var mapBounds = myMap.getBounds();
  var bbox = [
    mapBounds.getWest(),
    mapBounds.getSouth(),
    mapBounds.getEast(),
    mapBounds.getNorth()
  ].join(',');

  var query = '[out:json];(node[amenity=fire_station](bbox);node[amenity=police](bbox););out+center;';

  var url = 'https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?bbox=' + bbox +
    '&data=' + query;

  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.onload = function() {
    if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
      var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
      processOverpassReply(data);
    }
  };
  request.send();
}

var startPosition = [49.85349, 8.65859];
var zoomOptions = {
  minZoom: 12,
  maxZoom: 16
};

var myMap = L.map('myMap', zoomOptions).setView(startPosition, 14);
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(myMap);

var groups = {
  fire_station: L.featureGroup().addTo(myMap),
  police: L.featureGroup().addTo(myMap),
  routes: L.geoJSON().addTo(myMap)
};

var overlays = {
  'Show fire stations': groups.fire_station,
  'Show police stations': groups.police,
  'Show OSRM routes': groups.routes
};

L.control.layers(null, overlays, {
  collapsed: false
}).addTo(myMap);

var startMarker = L.marker(startPosition, { draggable: true })
  .on('dragend', function(ev) { groups.routes.clearLayers(); })
  .bindPopup('You are here')
  .addTo(myMap);

myMap.on('dragend zoomend', sendOverpassRequest);

sendOverpassRequest();
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#myMap {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet@1/dist/leaflet.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet@1/dist/leaflet-src.min.js"></script>

<div id="myMap"></div>
```